# TypeError: Elixir.ready is not a function

Tags: laravel, gulp, laravel-elixir

In my gulp file...

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
require('laravel-elixir-vueify');
/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Elixir Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Elixir provides a clean, fluent API for defining some basic Gulp tasks
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for our application, as well as publishing vendor resources.
 |
 */

elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.sass('app.scss')
    .browserify('app.js')
    .browserSync({proxy: 'mysite.dev'});
});
```

Comment: Refer to this issue - https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-elixir-vueify/issues/26

Answer (score 1):

Try after installing `laravel-elixir-webpack-official`.

```
npm install laravel-elixir-webpack-official --save-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

Try and paste this in your package.json.

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "prod": "gulp --production",
    "dev": "gulp watch"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "jquery": "^3.1.0",
    "laravel-elixir": "^6.0.0-14",
    "laravel-elixir-vue-2": "^0.2.0",
    "laravel-elixir-webpack-official": "^1.0.2",
    "lodash": "^4.16.2",
    "vue": "^2.0.1",
    "vue-resource": "^1.0.3"
  }
}
```

Then run;

> npm install
>
> gulp